# linux eclipse: run a shell command as the pre-build command

Tags: linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

How can I have the pre-build step in eclipse/CDT (Linux) run a simple shell command, echo specifically.  I think eclipse has a screwed up value for PKG_CONFIG_PATH and want to see what Linux thinks the value is.

Comment: After googling the actual error message for this problem (who would have guessed exactly that test would be found!!??) , I found out that eclipse did had messed up PKG_CONFIG_PATH.  See here for the solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7928228/pkg-config-fails-to-find-packages-when-run-from-eclipse  answer #1.  I still would like to know the answer to my question should I need it in future sor some other bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the covers, Eclipse uses "make".  You can simly edit the project's makefile:

- help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_makefile.htm

You can also create an:

> "External Tool", which is up there beside the Debug and Run buttons in
>   the toolbar. Then I tell the external tool to run the shell with the
>   configure script and any of it's arguments as arguments to the tool.
>
> http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/61866/

Comment: great idea, except the makefiles get rebuilt from XML whenever something effects their contents.  As for the external tool, gosh that seems complicated!